# In jQuery.getScript(), how do we set the charset type to utf-8?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery.getScript("url", function(){});
```

The jQuery.getScript("url", function(url, callback, charset).. 
Can it be done like this ?

Comment: getScript basically just appends a script tag to the page, there is no way to set the charset.

Comment: Yes agreed. But my url has script which has japanese characters. When i retrieve i am getting as ??? in my UI. If i set the <meta charset="UTF-8" in my html page. still it couldnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Charset is not intended controlled on getScript function, you just control your page charset type on the page it self or via server side

Try to add `<meta charset="utf-8">` on html head tag.

Comment: setting <meta charset="utf-8"> in html head tag.This is not working. Any other way out to load javascript and set the character set.. IF so please specify.